# Building Visual Studio project on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, visual-studio, continuous-integration

I have set up a CI server for our .NET projects. To build those projects I want to use the Visual Studio executable `devenv.exe`.

This worked out perfectly during the "evaluation period". Now these 30 days are over, to keep using Visual Studio on my Desktop computer, I just updated my license with one mouseclick. Doing this on the server allows me to build using the GUI, but when running `devenv.exe` programatically with the required parameters, I am receiving an error that the evaluation license expired, even though I renewed it.

I have already tried a clean reinstall, which did not fix the issue for me. Visual Studio on the server is connected to the same account I am successfully using on my Desktop PC.

Is there a known fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The license is somehow related to the user that launches Visual Studio. So to to automatically build projects with `devenv.exe`, the building agent has to run under the same user account, that installed an launched Visual Studio.